# jquery BBQ - if parameter doesn't exist function

Tags: jquery, jquery-bbq

How would I use jquery BBQ to check if a parameter exists and if it does not then run a function?

I'm assuming that `$.deparam.fragment().srhTerm;` is what I would use, however if `srhTerm` doesn't exist in the url, does it return false or null?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will return `undefined`.

This is what the test could look like:

```
if( typeof($.deparam.fragment().srhTerm) == 'undefined' ) {
    // do stuff
}
```